# I can't find Microsoft Test and Lab Manager 2010 beta 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

I'm looking to install the beta2 version of MTLM for evaluation purposes, but I can't find a download for it.

- I can find Visual Studio 2010 beta 2, but that doesn't seem to have it.
- There's "Team Lab Manager" beta 2, which appears to be concerned with managing lots of Hyper-V VM's and nothing to do with testing
- There's "Test Elements" 2010, but I want to evaluate the full version, not a cut down 'elements' version
- There's Team Foundation Server 2010 - is it bundled with that?

The Microsoft and MSDN websites are a twisted maze of confusion and aren't helping me. Is MTLM bundled with any of the above products, or is it a seperate download from somewhere else?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

OK. I installed VS2010 beta 2, and even though at no point did it make any mention of MTLM, after install in the start menu there is a link to Microsoft Test and Lab Manager. Hooray!

When I run it the first thing it asks me for is the TFS server, and it doesn't appear to work with our existing TFS2008 server, so I guess I'm off to download that!

Comment: Yes, MTLM sits on top of TFS, so that's a prerequisite.